# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'next_price' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

Tried troubleshooting this for a bit but thought it might be easy for someone more experienced... but it keeps turning up Error 1054. The goal is to sum both up and present a single number.

```
select sum(next_price)
from
(
    select sum(sub.next_price)
    from sub
    left join account on account.acctid = sub.acctid
    where sub.date_created >= curdate()
    and sub.date_created < curdate()+1
    and account.type <> 'internal'

UNION ALL

    select sum(sub.next_price)*-1
    from sub
    left join account on account.acctid = sub.acctid
    where sub.date_closed >= curdate()
    and sub.date_closed < curdate()+1
    and account.type <> 'internal'
) as Temp

group by next_price
```

Comment: In your first line, should't it be `sub.next_price`?

Comment: @KobyDouek nop, it's a temporary table called Temp, so maybe `Temp.next_price` but not sub.

Comment: you didn't alias next price in your union.  `select sum(sub.next_price)` needs to be  `select sum(sub.next_price) next_price`  Additionally why are you summing next_price and grouping by it?

Comment: Do you have any records in account which would have a date_created >=current_date and date_Closed>=curdate?  if so it would occur in both sets and union all would keep both records.  is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no column with the name `next_price` in the temporary table `Temp`, that's why you're getting that message.

`sum(sub.next_price)` does not create you a column with the name `next_price`.

Try this query :

```
select sum(t.price) as next_price
from
(
select sum(sub.next_price) as price
from sub
left join account on account.acctid = sub.acctid
where sub.date_created >= curdate()
and sub.date_created < curdate()+1
and account.type <> 'internal'

UNION ALL

select sum(sub.next_price)*-1 as price
from sub
left join account on account.acctid = sub.acctid
where sub.date_closed >= curdate()
and sub.date_closed < curdate()+1
and account.type <> 'internal'
) as Temp as t

group by t.next_price
```

Comment: I dropped that second 'as t' and the group by and it seems to work now! Thanks

Comment: @skyrunner Yes you can drop the temp table alias, that's optional, it just make it more readable :) glad to help, if that solved your problem mark it as a solution ;) have a good day